# How to Collapse the first accordion when the last one is completed?

Tags: javascript

I'm using twitter boostrap for the first time & am using the collapsible accordion.

I wants to trigger the first accordion open when the last one get completed. Its working in the forward directions. But the control is not working fine for me when i looking in the backward direction. Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

[Just use a jQuery cookie and make a modification to the accordion script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733238/bootstrap-collapse-accordion-return-to-same-section-when-navigating-away-and-ba)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var last=$.cookie('activeAccordionGroup');
    if (last!=null) {
        //remove default collapse settings
        $("#accordion2 .collapse").removeClass('in');
        //show the last visible group
        $("#"+last).collapse("show");
    }
});

//when a group is shown, save it as the active accordion group
$("#accordion2").bind('shown', function() {
    var active=$("#accordion2 .in").attr('id');
    $.cookie('activeAccordionGroup', active)
});
```