# nested Gridview never remain expanded after page reload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datagridview

I have following code that is used to show/hide in nested grid view.

**Problem** : when i reload the page my **selected** **item** hides, but i need it showing even after page reload.  In short the selected item from **gridview** remains showing even the page reloaded...

Here is code:

```
 $(function () {
            $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
                debugger;
                $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
                 $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
            });

            $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
                //  debugger;
                $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
                $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
            });
        });
```

Any idea , guidelines to achieve the following

Answer (score 0):

your nested gridview is inside a toggle div use this link to keep it open
[Bootstrap accordion prevent collapse on postback in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552674/bootstrap-accordion-prevent-collapse-on-postback-in-asp-net)