# Retain Accordion State on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have a question about retaining the state of the collapsed panels on postback within an accordion. I just need to make the page operate so that after a postback, the accordion state appears unmodified.

I've tried using a hidden field as per:
[Bootstrap accordion prevent collapse on postback in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552674/bootstrap-accordion-prevent-collapse-on-postback-in-asp-net)

and also using jquery cookie and following the advice here, even in regards to updating the JS due to bootstrap 4 changes.
[Retain Twitter Bootstrap Collapse state on Page refresh/Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733238/retain-twitter-bootstrap-collapse-state-on-page-refresh-navigation)

So importing this js:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js

And using the code below:

Using .NET Core and Razor pages.
 **html**

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Collapsible Group Item #2
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit,
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form method="get">
    <button>Hi</button>
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        //when a group is shown, save it as the active accordion group
        $("#accordion").on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            var active = $("#accordion .show").attr('id');
            $.cookie('activeAccordionGroup', active);
          //  alert(active);
        });
        $("#accordion").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $.removeCookie('activeAccordionGroup');
        });
        var last = $.cookie('activeAccordionGroup');
        if (last != null) {
            //remove default collapse settings
            $("#accordion .panel-collapse").removeClass('show');
            //show the account_last visible group
            $("#" + last).addClass("show");
        }
    });
```

No errors messages, it just doesn't work unfortunately. Any help or advice will be greatly received.

Comment: Don't use cookies. Either use localStorage or simply include the fragment for the section that should be expanded in the redirect URL. Then apply some JS to check for the fragment and expand the associated section.

Comment: Thanks Chris, While I appreciate the feedback, I haven't had much luck looking this up. Do you have any resources you can suggest? Or any JSFiddles that might be useful? Sorry.