# Bootstrap collapse panel keeping a div open after a submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an accordion **div (panel-collapse)**, at the end of the **panel** I have a **submit button**, initially, `all the panel div are closed`, I want to keep the state of the div the same after the submit reload.

```
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Collapsible panel</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should use ajax methods to do this; Otherwise you should sent all status to server and reset them on backing in client

Comment: how can I get the status of a collapse div ?

Comment: What's your sarverside language?

Comment: I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733238/retain-twitter-bootstrap-collapse-state-on-page-refresh-navigation

Answer (score 0):

On a regular form submit the page gets reloaded and resets everything, but if you submit the form Asynchronously using ajax nothing will change on your page. Using php + jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#submitButton",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $("#formID").serialize();

    $.post("your_php_file.php",formData,function(response) {
        console.log(response); 
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way to preserve setting without async requests is using cookies.
You can set them via Javascript:
(http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Probably like assigning an array of active collapse panels

```
var active_panels=[0,1,2];
$.cookie('active_panels', JSON.stringify(active_panels))
```

Without jQuery see W3C specification