# Keep the state of the bootstrap sidebar when reloading page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, metronic

I am using a HTML template called Metronic to build a backend for myself. This HTML template offers the possibility to collapse the sidebar in the template I choose. However, the sidebar doesn't keep her state.

Here you can test the template: https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/?page=index&demo=default

I want to program it so the sidebar keeps here state when reloading the page. I already found some solutions with the plugin called `js.cookie` to save the state of the sidebar menu at the clients computer.

However, the problem I am facing is I really don't know which class or id I have to call in order to get the current state of the sidebar and depending on this state and the state saved to the cookie, toggle the sidebar...

This is what I have tried so far:
[Retain Twitter Bootstrap Collapse state on Page refresh/Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733238/retain-twitter-bootstrap-collapse-state-on-page-refresh-navigation)

My code so far:

```
<script>
    var last=$.cookie('menuToggled');
    console.log(last);

    if (last!=null) {
        //remove default collapse settings
        $("#page-sidebar-menu-ul").removeClass('page-sidebar-menu-closed');
        //show the last visible group
        $("#"+last).collapse("show");
    }

    $("#page-sidebar-menu").bind('shown', function() {
        $.cookie('menuToggled', "page-sidebar-menu")
    });
</script>
```

I have assigned the id `page-sidebar-menu` and `page-sidebar-menu-ul` to my template. On the page linked above the id `page-sidebar-menu` is `m_ver_menu` and the id `page-sidebar-menu-ul` is the `ul` element followed by the id `m_ver_menu`.

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank You!

Comment: For cookies in JS you don't need to use a plugin. Also with a code snippet it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: I can paste you my code here but I don't think it will help at all cause I guess it is completely wrong.. wait a sec

Comment: Check [this](https://keenthemes.com/forums/topic/save-current-menu-status/) out.  It suggests to make ajax calls to "remember" you menu state.