# Adding 'active' class to open Bootstrap accordion item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried this solution:

[Twitter bootstrap: adding a class to the open accordion title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918801/twitter-bootstrap-adding-a-class-to-the-open-accordion-title)

But to no avail, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

This is the accordion:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span5">
                    <img src="img/smartlist/user-icon.png" class="user"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                    href="#collapseOne">Austin Wang</a>

                </div>
                <div class="span7">
                    <img class="envelope" src="img/smartlist/envelope.png"> <a href="#">Seller Drip</a>

                    <img class="new" src="img/smartlist/new-icon.png"> <a href="#">New</a>

                    <img class="messages" src="img/smartlist/bubbles.png"> <a href="#">8 Days</a>

                    <img class="accordion-action pull-right" src="img/smartlist/plus-box.png"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12 top-links"> <a href="#" class="active">Email Template</a>
 <a href="#">Home Price Evaluation Offer</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="arrow-up"></div>
                <div class="row-fluid grey-body">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <label>Subject</label>
                        <input type="text" class="text-field">
                        <label>Body</label>
                        <textarea rows="10"></textarea>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <div class="form">
                                <button type="submit" class="send-button">Send</button> <a href="#" class="call">Call</a>
 <a href="#" class="skip">Skip</a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-right radio">
                                <input type="radio">
                                <label>BCC Me</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then my JS at the bottom:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/less-1.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".collapse").collapse()   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('.accordion-body').on('show', function (e) {
     $(e.target).prev('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('active');
});

$('.accordion-body').on('hide', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').not($(e.target)).removeClass('active');
});

});
</script>
```

I really don't know much about JS, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: doesn't general accordian controls add and remove active class by default?

Comment: Which bootstrap version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

If you see in that fiddle, he has defined one css rule for

```
.active {
    background-color: Blue;   
}
```

In your case, you are successfully applying the css class to the element, but the class is not defined. (Or you haven't posted it in the question)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean-- when I look at the code in the inspector, the active class is never applied to begin with, so it wouldn't matter what CSS i assign to it?

Comment: I see, I tried with the code you posted, and the class being assigned properly. May be you could `console.log( $(e.target).prev('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle') )` and see if it finds the element.

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8CcuK/), check in inspector, active class is applied properly. and I just added one `.active` rule [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8CcuK/1/) and its getting background color.

Comment: Yes, that does work there-- how would I modify the code to add the .active to the .accordion-heading element?

Comment: Actually, the only reason that .active styling works is because other things have an .active class on their own. The javascript isn't what's adding it. The element that has a blue background isn't an .accordion-toggle class or link.

Comment: Now I am confused, where exactly you want the active class? I can't seem to understand your problem. You could even use `$(this).prev().addClass('active');` in `show` and `$(this).prev().removeClass('active');` in `hide`.

Comment: Sorry! I want the active class on the .accordion-heading element.

Comment: `$(this).prev().addClass('active');` adds the `active` class on `accordion-heading`. Try it

Comment: Like this?     

    $(".collapse").collapse()   

    $(function() {

    $('.accordion-body').on('show', function (e) {
 $(this).prev().addClass('active');
    });

    $('.accordion-body').on('hide', function (e) {
    $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
    });

   });
   </script>

Comment: Yes, Did you try it? whats the issue you faced?

Comment: It still wasn't adding the class to accordion heading -- I genuinely have no idea why.

Comment: Try to debug it man, `console.log()` on every step, on every selector. and you shall find what the problem is.. Good Luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$('.accordion-body').on('show',
  function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.accordion-heading').addClass('active') 
  }
)

$('.accordion-body').on('hide',
  function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.accordion-heading').removeClass('active') 
  }
)
```

Comment: Hello - this doesn't work for me -- is it to do with where I'm placing it in the code?

Comment: This code has to be run after DOMElements are ready, otherwise $('.accordion-body') will find nothing and nothing will happen.
[Executing when dom is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) See the examples on this page.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option
1. Add on click event to **.accordion-toggle**
1. Remove active class from all elements with class - accordion-toggle
2. Check aria-expanded flag, if it is true then add active to the clicked element

```
    $(function() {
       $("a").on('click',function(){
         $('.accordion-toggle ').removeClass('active')

         if($(this).attr('aria-expanded')!== false){
             console.log('add');
                        $(this).addClass('active')
           }
        })
});
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pVNxWw