# Bootstrap 3 Collapse - adding active class to open panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

firstly here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/h38jn324/

Simple question when a panel is clicked (and it expands to show it's respective content), a class 'active' needs to be added to 'panel-heading'.

I found similar question but none of those solutions seem to work (strangely). Any help would be appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="accordion-2 panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    Our Mission
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /#collapseOne -->
    </div><!-- /.panel -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                Success Stories
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
        </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div><!-- /#collapseTwo -->
</div><!-- /.panel -->
<div class="panel panel-default last">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                Our Story
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
        </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div><!-- /#collapseTwo -->
</div><!-- /.panel -->
```

JS Code:

```
jQuery('.accordion-2 .panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function () {   
jQuery('.accordion-2 .panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]').removeClass('actives');
$(this).addClass('actives');
```

});

Comment: The `actives` name is a typo? Should be `active`?

Comment: Hi, dose not matter, no class is being added.

Comment: Oh, of course. The answer you selected as correct was already there when I commented. I've just informed you of a possible typo, not that the code was right.

Comment: Oh, in that case, thanks a lot thiagobraga

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.panel-heading a').click(function() {
    $('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
    if(!$(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in'))
        $(this).parents('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h38jn324/350/)**

**Update 1:**
To set a panel as active by default on the first load, just add the `active` class manually to the `panel-heading` in HTML code.

**Update 2:**
Although this answer is marked as accepted answer, I highly recommend to take a look at the `Blizwire` answer too.

Comment: You can use `$(this).parents('.panel-heading')` instead of `$(this).parent().parent()`.

Comment: Hi Moshtaf, A small addition could be helpful, the class needs to be loaded when the page loads

Comment: What class? `accordion-2`?

Comment: @chandan You can put this class directly in HTML to avoid more one JavaScript function and just use the function when the user clicks. Use `<div class="panel-heading active">` for that panel you want.

Comment: Hi Moshtaf, oh yes I forgot, but I thought may be in could be done via js. Thank a ton.

Comment: @chandan: it could be done using JS, you can use this on first load: `$('.panel-collapse .collapse .in').parent().children('.panel-heading').addClass('actives');`. but really it's not the best soulution, the best solution as mentioned is add class manually.

Comment: This solution could fail if there are multiple ways to open and close a collapsable element (outside of just clicking the targeted 'a' element). Bootstrap has a built-in event for showing/hiding collapsable panels which should be used instead of a regular click event. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @Moshtaf The class actives still when you open and close the same heading!

Comment: I had to make a small update on the above anwser with a condition if the clicked element had class ('actives') to only remove it and not re-apply it again.

Answer (score 14):

The current answer (by Moshtaf) is using a standard click event. However, Bootstrap has a built-in event for opening/closing of collapsable items, as pointed out by Jurriaan, which is much safer to use (a click on the link doesn't necessarily mean that the panel is shown). Here's a clean solution, inspired by Jurriaan's solution, with minimal amount of code and jQuery selectors. http://codepen.io/martinkrulltott/pen/mPgYgQ

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
  });

  $('.panel-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: This is best approach since solution of Moshtaf is not working properly. When you click on same panel it does not change class.

Answer (score 5):

These answers didn't work for me for in some cases: Multiple panel groups on 1 page, or clicking on the same title to hide a panel. This adaption from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24033761/842740 works as a general solution and I added code for setting the default open panel on active state.

```
$('.panel-group .panel-collapse.in').prev().addClass('active');
$('.panel-group')
  .on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    $(e.target).prev('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
  })
  .on('hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    $(e.target).prev('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

For someone who is looking for CSS solution and I tired this only in **Bootstrap 4**:

**HTML**

```
<a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> Open Collapse </a>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-block card-outline-primary">
    <h3 class="text-center">Date Goes Here</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
[data-toggle="collapse"]:not(.collapsed) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('activestate')) {
      $(this).removeClass('activestate');
    } else {
      $('.panel-heading').removeClass('activestate');
      $(this).addClass('activestate');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none !important
}
.panel-heading:hover,
.panel-heading:focus,
.panel-heading:hover a,
.panel-heading:focus a {
  color: #c9b27e;
  text-decoration: none !IMPORTANT;
}
.activestate {
  background-color: #c9b27e !IMPORTANT;
  color: white !important;
  display: block;
}
.activestate:hover a {
  color: black;
}
.panel-heading {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="accordion-2 panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading activestate">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
               Our Mission
              </a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
          mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#collapseOne -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
               Success Stories
              </a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
          mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#collapseTwo -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel -->
  <div class="panel panel-default last">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
               Our Story
              </a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
          mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#collapseTwo -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel -->
</div>
<!-- /.accordion-2 -->
```

I think that this is more logical.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers require panel-heading. All this requires is the data-target.

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse]').each(function() {
    var $collapse_btn = $(this),
        $collapse_target =  $(this.getAttribute('data-target'));

    $collapse_target.on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        $collapse_btn.addClass('collapsed');
    }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
        $collapse_btn.removeClass('collapsed');
    });
});
```